# Laptop LCD screen line defect(?)

Tags: laptop, display, lcd

[image: Photo]

The left part works well. But there are various colors of thin vertical lines and black background. Which problem does my laptop have?

Is this LCD problem or mainboard problem?
I wonder which component I should replace to make it working well.

It's Lenovo G460 (14" display)

Comment: Is removing the graphic driver and trying out has same effect? May not be really the whole board problem. Just the video chip issue? or could be a LCD issue too. So boot into Safe mode and try.

One more, do you have the same issue even at the boot up? perhaps pre OS boot time or BIOS.

Answer (score 3):

It couldn't be the screen inverter.  All that does is provide high AC voltage to the Cold Cathode Fluorescent Light that illuminates most LCD screens.  When there is trouble with the inverter, you just have a dark screen.  It would never cause the issues you are seeing there, because it in no way connects to the screen in a way that could cause that.

Corrupt Video Ram *could* look like that, but typically is expressed over the whole screen.  Yes, there are examples of GPU issues that can be selective... but in general you'd see the issue from the BIOS On.  In fact, Video Ram issues will persist even when not using your display.  Connect an external monitor, and see if you can see those lines.  You can even see corrupt Video Ram issues over a [remote VNC connection](http://www.citronix.net/blog/odd-video-artifacts-reveal-memory-corruption/).

[image: Video Corruption over VNC]

What you are showing us is most likely damage to the LCD panel itself.  Again, you should eliminate the motherboard as a suspect by testing the external monitor connection first, but those lines on the screen look like separation of the LCD panels from the connection at the very top of the screen.  People can encounter these lines sometimes when they have always opened their laptop screen from one corner, constantly putting a twist on the screen.  Over time, that twist separates the LCD panel itself from the thin PCB at the back of the screen.  It separates in places, and those lines (not that many at first) will typically appear.

Again.  I'm not saying that twisting your screen caused this.  I'm not even saying that it IS a damaged screen.  But corrupt Video Ram, or an overheating GPU doesn't create [that type of artifacting](http://www.playtool.com/pages/artifacts/artifacts.html).  That's why before you go out and spend any money, just do that simple test.  Connect an external monitor.  If the problem persists on the external monitor, you know you need to replace the motherboard.  If the problem does NOT persist on the external monitor, you know it is just the LCD panel itself.

Comment: Good logic and detail.  I do give it about 98% odds that the LCD panel is just damaged, though.

Comment: @Shinrai That, and if you do a Google image search for "damaged LCD", screens that have been physically broken show the same asymmetrical patterns.  I've personally seen and replaced damaged screens that displayed like that, but when someone wants to know themselves for sure, it's a simple enough test to be able to perform.

Answer (score 1):

I am experiencing the same issue with my laptop right now.  I notice it commonly when I try to wake it up from sleep mode.  As it happening I tilted up my laptop almost 90 degrees and it stop.  I am thinking it may be a connection issue between the motherboard and the display.  I connected it to another monitor and it works fine even when my labtop screen was showing the vertical lines. Plus it's more prevalent when I close the screen and open it back up.

Answer (score 0):

Ouch! My first instinct says it's your video memory. As zenwalker asked, does it occur during the BIOS as well? What kind of graphics hardware do you have? If not, it could be the inverter or the panel. Odds are your computer wouldn't boot if it was the motherboard.